# How to disable android keyboard in android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am creating a calculator app where i have an edittext where the result is shown.I want the data to be entered in the edit text only on clicking the number buttons NOT by the android keyboard.How do i disable the keyboard in my android app.Please help!

Comment: please do a search before posting a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: You can try like : Disable the `EditText` and append number to the `EditText` on the number `Button` click.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
editText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL)
```

Or

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoginNameEditText)).setFocusable(false);
```

Or

```
editText.setKeyListener(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) :

```
InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
    EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ed.getWindowToken(), 0);  

    ed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
            imm.showSoftInput(ed, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);  

        }
    });
```

or

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode (SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden);
```

Comment: The android keyboard still appears on uploading on my phone.

Comment: uploading on my phone ?

Answer (score 0):

If other situations you can prevent the keyboard showing simply using in the manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

In this way the Android keyboard will not auto-open but is shown only if you click directly the EditText

Answer (score 0):

Just posting an Answer what @yahya already commented.

You should consider using a `TextView` which is not editable and hence won't make any calls to the Keyboard.

In `onClick()` event of your button's call the `setText(String)` method and the apply the text you wish. :)

Ypu can also easily append things as `setText(yourTextView.getText().toString + "Your New Text");`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kindly try this: For this you no need any Widgets Context...

```
InputMethodManager miInputManager = (InputMethodManager) Activity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
miInputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Activity.this
            .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

for `<activity>` in `Android_Manifest.xml`

Comment: Did you try this @user3627802